# Firebase : site not deployed and empty firebase.json file

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I am trying to set up a very simple website using firebase and the hosting service. I installed node.js v6 following [the official instructions](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/) provided on their website for Ubuntu. Then I installed firebase and tried to deploy my website following these [instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/quickstart).

Unfortunately, I ran through several problems.

The `firebase login` worked fine and the `firebase init` command appeared to have worked fine too. I then added a very simple `index.html` file to my folder and then used `firebase deploy`. The command output told me the website had been successfully deployed, but it was not. The website is not found when I try to reach it with my browser, and the firebase online hosting utility tells me nothing was deployed.

I then checked my `firebase.json` file and noticed it only contained this :

```
{}
```

It's been more than a day now, so I don't think their servers could be that slow at deploying my website, which is very light.

I've tried reinstalling everything, but nothing changed unfortunately...

Comment: Just to be sure, did you add a public folder in your project folder, and inside the public folder, is that where you added the index.html?

Comment: did you solve this?